# What does "disciplinary" mean in this sentence from the NY Times?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

> The claim is not simply that **disciplinary** expertise confers moral and political superiority, but that historians, because of their training, are uniquely objective observers: “As historians, we consider diverse viewpoints while acknowledging our own limitations and subjectivity.”

I used Oxford Advanced Learner Dictionary 8 and Macmillan Dictinonary for the word *disciplinary*. And they both produce the same result: "connected with the punishment of people who do not obey rules". This meaning really confuses me, actually I think it's not correspondent to the whole meaning of the sentence, I mean if I think "disciplinary expertise"  is the same as "high level-knowledge", the sentence is more clearer. But why two famous Dictionaries produce like that? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The online edition of the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary lists a second definition for [*disciplinary*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disciplinary?q=disciplinary) that is more relevant here: "connected with an area of knowledge, especially a subject that people study in a university"

Comment: Similarly, if you look up the [noun _discipline_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/discipline_1) in the Macmillan Dictionary online, you'll find that definition 2 is "a subject that people study, especially at a university." Hence, one meaning of _disciplinary_ as an adjective can be "of or relating to a subject that people study, especially at a university."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could the word discipline be used rather than disciplinary?

MW dictionary for discipline: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discipline 
#3 definition is "a field of study".

The author is using a root word (discipline) with common usage with a common suffix.  Not all prefixes and suffixes of all words are in the dictionary; These are not normally defined individually unless the word has a different meaning.

Answer (score 9):

Because *disciplinary* simply means concerned with discipline, and *discipline* can mean not chastisement but field of knowledge, *disciplinary expertise* means expertise in a particular area.

That is, it is the same thing as *domain expertise*.

Compare with [*interdisciplinary*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/interdisciplinary) meaning related to more than one branch of knowledge. Without the *inter-* part, it simply means related to a branch of knowledge.